How to extract the provider type in callbacks in nextauth
I am trying to extract the provider type in the callback section in sessions. Based on the provider type, I want to have a different logic for returning the session.
export const options: NextAuthOptions = {
    providers: [
        GitHubProvider({
            clientId: process.env.GITHUB_ID as string,
            clientSecret: process.env.GITHUB_SECRET as string
        }),
        CredentialsProvider({
            name: "Credentials",
            credentials: {
                ... // logic for signup
            },
            async authorize(credentials){
                ... // logic for checking the username and password
        })
    ],
    pages:{
        signIn: '/signin',
        
    },
    secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
    callbacks:{
        session: async ({session, token}: any)=>{

            // Need to extract the provider type here to perform different logic


            console.log('session in options:',token)
            try{    
                 session.user.username = await getUsername(parseInt(token.sub))
            }catch(e){
                console.error(e)
                return null
            }
            console.log('session in options:',session)
            return session
        }
    }

}

I am looking for something like this provided below to perform separate logic.
session: async ({session, token, user}: any)=>{
            console.log('session in options:',token)
            try{
                if(user.provider === 'Credentials'){
                    session.user.username = await getUsername(parseInt(token.sub))
                }else{
                    Console.log('another logic here')  // different logic here
                }
                
            }catch(e){
                console.error(e)
                return null
            }
            console.log('session in options:',session)
            return session
        }

I hope this makes it clear what I am trying to achieve
